# Checking collisions for a given robot state tutorial

Tags: ros, collision-map

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Guys,
I have a problem with the following tutorial:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/motion_planning_environment/Tutorials/Tutorial%20A
when I call
roslaunch pr2_arm_navigation_tutorials laser-perception.launch
the collision map does not show on rviz.
Instead I get the following message:

[ WARN] [1322669029.655800639]: You've passed in true for auto_start for the C++ action server you should always pass in false to avoid race conditions.
[laser_clear_objects-5] process has died [pid 16360, exit code -6].

What is the problem?
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12162/checking-collisions-for-a-given-robot-state-tutorial/) by [zamboni](https://answers.ros.org/users/1449/zamboni/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2011-11-30

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That tutorial only works for Diamondback - I added a note to that effect at the top of the tutorial.  For a roughly equivalent Electric tutorial use this one:  [Checking State Validity](http://www.ros.org/wiki/arm_navigation/Tutorials/Planning%20Scene/Checking%20State%20Validity)

---

Originally posted by [egiljones](https://answers.ros.org/users/82/egiljones/) with karma: 2031 on 2011-11-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2